# using filters in component binding html attribute in angularjs (causing $digest() errors)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to filter an array of objects using an AngularJS filter `filter : {completed:true}` inside an html attribute that is in fact a binding itself. **Is this possible, or should I do this in another way**? More examples and code below.

### How to reproduce

1. See plnkr with the failing code at http://plnkr.co/edit/JdiLEIyji2pHd3eeNMUL?p=preview
2. One can also see code snippets & link to original repo below

---

#### UPDATE 30/03/2017:

Found a possible solution with introducing an extra binding, check answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43112663/1155847 below for a possible solution. Open to any other suggestions.

**BUT** using a filter expression like `<todo-list todo-items="$ctrl.todoItems | filter:{completed:true}"></todo-list>` still causes `$digest()` cycle errors. I've created a branch in my repo to reproduce: https://github.com/aredfox/todo-angularjs-typescript/tree/filter-inside-attribute-digest-errors.
=> `git clone https://github.com/aredfox/todo-angularjs-typescript` + cd to repo dir and then `git checkout filter-inside-attribute-digest-errors` + `npm install && npm run`

---

### Code Snippets & Usage

Below I have a TL;DR view of the code that's the most important to my question, for the full repo, you can look at [this commit](https://github.com/aredfox/todo-angularjs-typescript/commit/4bd5df189cd7d6d95f398873aecc37dcbda3cac5#diff-ce9fd88c060b30673e9b704607157663) which holds all the source files in detail.

#### `todo-list` directive HTML declaration & usage

- Normal usage of the directive: `<todo-list todo-items="$ctrl.todoItems"></todo-list>` - this works fine and lists out the `title` of each `TodoItem` as programmed inside the `todo-list`.

**things I tried**:

- What I tried to do with a filter, *which is not working*: `<todo-list todo-items="$ctrl.todoItems | filter : {completed:true}"></todo-list>`. But this gave me the following error: `Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`.

#### `todo-list` component definition

**typescript**
    class TodoList implements angular.IComponentOptions {
        template: string;
        bindings: any;

```
    constructor() {
        this.template = require('./todo-list.component.html');
        this.bindings = {
            todoItems: '<'
        };
    }
}
```

**js**

```
var TodoList = (function () {
    function TodoList() {
        this.template = require('./todo-list.component.html');
        this.bindings = {
            todoItems: '<'
        };
    }
    return TodoList;
}());
```

---

#### TodoItem model

The model I'm using is an array of `TodoItem`s. The definition (typescript / js) below:

**typescript**

```
class TodoItem {
    constructor(
        public title: string,
        public completed: boolean
    ) { }
}
```

**js**

```
var TodoItem = (function () {
    function TodoItem(title, completed) {
        this.title = title;
        this.completed = completed;
    }
    return TodoItem;
}());
```

Comment: Filters work in Angular Expression but the `in` operator does not. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).

Comment: @georgeawg tried it like `<todo-list todo-items="$ctrl.todoItems | filter : {completed:true}"></todo-list>` but running into `$digest()` error/cycles. See editied question above, I added a branch where one can reproduce it. `git clone https://github.com/aredfox/todo-angularjs-typescript` + cd to repo dir and then `git checkout filter-inside-attribute-digest-errors` + `npm install && npm run`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.** Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. It is not reasonable to ask readers to clone code from GitHub to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @georgeawg ok, I created a plnkr that reproduces the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/JdiLEIyji2pHd3eeNMUL?p=preview and edited the question. Hope that's better, as it is a valid question in itself, but I agree, a plnkr is better.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution for me, by doing the following:

### 1. todo-list.component.ts

Here I add another binding where the filter will act on (`filterBy`, which we can use in the `todo-list` as `filter-by`)

```
class TodoList implements angular.IComponentOptions {
    template: string;
    bindings: any;

    constructor() {
        this.template = require('./todo-list.component.html');
        this.bindings = {
            todoItems: '<',
            filterBy: '<'
        };
    }
}
```

the **template** looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="todoItem in $ctrl.todoItems | filter:$ctrl.filterBy">
    <span>{{ todoItem.title }}</span>
</div>
```

### 2. using `todo-list`

- `<todo-list todo-items="$ctrl.todoItems"></todo-list>` then results in showing all todoItems
- `<todo-list todo-items="$ctrl.todoItems" filter-by="{completed:true}"></todo-list>` shows the items that have the property completed set to true

Answer (score 0):

This may not be acceptable based on your use case, but an answer mentioned here - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/15874 worked for me.

You can use the binding =* to do a shallow watch on a collection.  This then uses two way binding, but unfortunately <* is not available yet.